# Avoid HTTP 500 on http_basic_authenticate_with if no auth provided in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 app that require authentication with

```
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "ILoveSO", password: "ItrustSOwithmypassword"
```

However it throws an error 500 when I try to test authentication failure (no http auth header provided).

> NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
>       app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in`'
>       app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `'

How can I send an HTTP 403 instead of failing on an undefined key ?

This is the code I use for my unit test:

```
assert_response :error,  get("ping")
```

Edit: While I was trying to debug this, I found out that if I shrieked down my only test file to :

```
  test "nothing" do
  end
```

I was still getting the error.

WTF is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this was a bit stupid.

Some variable was not initialized in test environment and the error was coming from that.

Note for myself: read more carefully the stack trace !!!